# jQuery - Setting .blur to a class

Tags: jquery, isnumeric

I'm trying to set a blur on all 'number' classes (which happen to be  tags).

My trial coding is;

```
$('.number').blur(function () {
        if ($.isNumeric($(this).val) == false) alert('false ' + $(this).val);
        else alert('true ' + $(this).val);
        }) ;
```

It seems $(this) doesn't pick up the  tag. Basically I want to be able to check whether the value is numeric of not.

Would be grateful any ideas/solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is a function and should be called with brackets.

Comment: Thanks! Must have been one of those mornings!

Answer (score 1):

`val` is a function.

```
$(this).val
```

should be

```
$(this).val()
```